# PHP7 SoapClient verify_peer_name: SOAP Error: Could not connect to host

Tags: php, curl, soap, paypal, php-7

My Paypal Code is not running with the option verify_peer_name => true. When I try the same Soap Request with option false it works, seems like a PHP7 Bug to me? This works for me with PHP5.3.
I always get the error:

**Could not connect to host**

I have installed the certificates on my server and I am also able to curl the url without problems, only the SoapClient is not working as supposed.

Does anybody know, what the parameter **verify_peer_name** really does?

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://xxx.paypal/the.wsdl",
    array(
        "trace" => 1,
        "location" => "https://xxx.paypal/the.wsdl",
        'exceptions' => 1,
        "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer'       => true,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => true,
                )
            )
        )
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found about verify_peer_name and got this.. Check if it can help u:
 peer_name string

```
Peer name to be used. If this value is not set, then the name is guessed based on the hostname used when opening the stream.
```

verify_peer boolean

```
Require verification of SSL certificate used.

Defaults to TRUE.
```

verify_peer_name boolean

```
Require verification of peer name.

Defaults to TRUE.
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the option verify_peer_name exactly check?

Comment: It requires verification and if you are not verifying the peer means you make your SSL connection insecure though, as you don't validate the info it gives you.

Comment: sorry, that is wrong. verify_peer validates the certificate and verify_peer_name does something else...

Comment: I tried to find about verify_peer_name and found the same result. So, if you find any other  answer, let me know.

Comment: What is the peer_name parameter?

Comment: We have already talked about it in the previous comments, now what are you asking?? can you explain...